# Changing binding mode on Slider caused to change value

Tags: wpf

I have sliders with twoway binding enabled at startup. But when I move them, moving is not smooth enought. So, I decide to change binding mode from twoway to onewaytosource after Thumbs.DragStarted event is called, but this lead to immediate changing value from 1 to 0.

My question is: How to prevent slider from changing its value during new binding?

My code behind is below.

```
    private void SliderCameraZ_OnDragStarted(object sender, DragStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            BindingExpression bindingExpression = ((Slider) sender).GetBindingExpression(Slider.ValueProperty);
            BindingOperations.ClearBinding((Slider) sender, Slider.ValueProperty);
            Binding binding = new Binding();
            binding.Path = bindingExpression.ParentBinding.Path;
            binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource;
            binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
            ((Slider)sender).SetBinding(Slider.ValueProperty, binding);

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.Message + exception.StackTrace + exception.TargetSite);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Dou you use .Net 4.5? Then you could [add a delay to your binding](http://10rem.net/blog/2011/12/02/wpf-45-adding-a-delay-to-your-binding-updates-to-reduce-noise).

Comment: And you've forgotten to specify the new binding source `binding.Source = bindingExpression.DataItem;`.

Comment: Yes, I use .Net 4.5, but setting delay to 500 changes nothing. When I apply binding to slider value, It still change immediately to from 1 to 0.

Comment: If you use the Delay you can avoid setting a new binding. Omit the SliderCameraZ_OnDragStarted. If Delay doesn't help probably changing to OneWayToSource will also doesn't help.

Comment: Can you write more detail? How I can avoid setting new binding if I need to change binding mode from TwoWay to OneWayToSource?

Comment: Moving the slider isn't smooth because whatever you update with binding takes to much time. The Delay reduces the update calls, no need to change the binding.

Comment: Ok, Now I see. But what if I need an immediate update of binded value? What I must do in such case?

Comment: `bindingExpression.UpdateSource();` should do the job.

Comment: Could you clarify this more detail? When bindingExpression.UpdateSource(); should be called? Do you have a simple example for using it? For example I need to change Binding mode from TwoWay to OneWayToSource. What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All was simple. I just need to store value of slider and restore it after new binding is set.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases it should be enough using the [`Delay` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.delay.aspx) introduced in .Net 4.5 to reduce the update calls taking to much time. For a sample see [Adding a delay to your binding updates to reduce noise](http://10rem.net/blog/2011/12/02/wpf-45-adding-a-delay-to-your-binding-updates-to-reduce-noise):

```
<StackPanel>
    <Slider x:Name="ValueSlider"
            Minimum="0" Maximum="100"
            Margin="20" Height="25"
            Value="{Binding ElementName=ValueText, Delay=500, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <TextBox x:Name="ValueText" Text="50"
             Width="100" Height="50" FontSize="20"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center" /> 
</StackPanel>
```

If you really need an immediate update you can still call [BindingExpression.UpdateSource Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.updatesource.aspx) respective [BindingExpression.UpdateTarget Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.updatetarget.aspx):

```
BindingExpression bindingExpression = ValueSlider.GetBindingExpression(Slider.ValueProperty);
bindingExpression.UpdateSource();
```

---

But your question is about preventing the value change after changing the binding mode. I've noticed that this only appears with `BindingMode.OneWayToSource`. Maybe you can avoid this by changing the sample above to

```
<StackPanel>
    <Slider x:Name="ValueSlider"
            Minimum="0" Maximum="100"
            Margin="20" Height="25"
            Value="50" />
    <TextBox x:Name="ValueText"
             Text="{Binding ElementName=ValueSlider, Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
             Width="100" Height="50" FontSize="20"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center" /> 
</StackPanel>
```

Now the `TextBox` is bound to `Slider` and not the other way round. `BindingMode.OneWayToSource` would be `BindingMode.OneWay` and a binding change shouldn't cause a value change.

```
BindingExpression bindingExpression = ValueText.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = bindingExpression.DataItem;
binding.Path = bindingExpression.ParentBinding.Path;
binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
ValueText.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer, but this is not exactly what I need. I need to change value from binded class which binded exactly to Slider and I cannot do how you proposed with slider and textbox, because I need to immediate update the real value (value which binded from my class). By the way, It is very strange that only OneWayToSource leads to such behavior. Do I have a woraround for this issue keeping in mind my wishes?

Comment: Sorry, maybe someone else has more inside knowledge to solve this issue. If possible try to use a background thread for the time consuming work to unburden the UI thread.